# Counter for real numbers

Tags: html, input, floating-point, numbers

I made an [online cheesy riddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese/316605#316605), where the user should input a float number. However, my input now allows the user to scroll only to integers:

```
<input style="width: 60px;" type="number" id="answer" placeholder="Answer" maxlength="3">
```

I cannot find another `type` that will allow the user to scroll to floats (which maybe is unrealistic, because how much would the user need to scroll to go from .1 to .2 for example).

Is there a simple workaround for my cheesy riddle in that case that web devs know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the step attribute on your input to the number of decimal places you need

```html
<input style="width: 60px;" step="0.1" type="number" id="answer" placeholder="Answer" maxlength="3">
```

Comment: I guess I was searching the internet with wrong keywords. Thank you! Off-topic: What did you think about my riddle? :)

Comment: Hahahaha, a geeky kinda tribute to Stackoverflow

Comment: Haha thanks Michael for the nice words, the upvote, and the help, cheers!